# Using Google Analytics with shiny.router

Tags: r, google-analytics, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to use Google Analytics with my Shiny app and I published it on shyniapps.io.

But in my app I use `shiny.router`, so it creates pages with `#!` symbols and all path of some page looks like `myapp/#!/page`.
Google Analytics displays this pas just as `myapp/`.
Also shinyapps creates path between `myapp` and `#!` which starts with `_w_` symbols (I think it's session code or something else). So in the end all path looks like `myapp/_w_00000000/#!/page` where `0` is random hex numbers (`0-f`).

I use just a standard Google Analytics script:

```
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||
        function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();
          a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
          a.async=1;
          a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })
      (window, document, 'script',
        '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-000000000-0', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

      </script>
```

So, how I could send to Google Analytics normal styled paths `myapp/page` instead displayed `myapp/_w_00000000/#!/page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, Google Analytics uses `location.pathname` to define separate pages. you might override this by passing `location.href` as an identification parameter:

```
...
ga('send', 'pageview', document.location.href);
```

Comment: I'm not experienced in JS, so after I changed `ga('send', 'pageview');` to `ga('send', 'pageview', document.location.href);` I got paths like `https://myapp/_w_00000000/#!/page`.
How I could send only last path (`/page`)?

Comment: https://myapp/_w_00000000/#!/page is the value of document.location.href
you might extract any part of it using regular expressions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match